# How do I change the deployment web page in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, deployment-descriptor, google-cloud-code

I'm trying to change the entry web page that gets launched in my Google App Engine deployment. It's a simple J2E web project, using IntelliJ with Cloud Code plugin. The default deployment points to 'index.jsp', which gets automatically created with the project. I want to change that, to point to a custom form I have built, e.g. 'form.xhtml'.

Steps I've been through so far...

- Created base Google App Engine (Standard)
- Configured GAE localhost
- Configured GAE deployment server

I can do this easily on the localhost server, by just changing the server URL, e.g. from *http://localhost:8080/* to *http://localhost:8080/Ex_1.xhtml*

I can't work out how to change this on the deployment server though. There's no URL option like there is with localhost. As a result, when I deploy my code it still just launches the default index.jsp.

I've looked through the GAE deployment descriptor documentation, but it doesn't mention how to do this. I'm sure it's a very simple change, I just can't put my finger on it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is of course not a proper solution, but if everything else fails, you can have index.jsp redirect to the page you want.

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved this, in case anyone else has a similar issue. You need to add the 'entry page' into web-xml, using the 'welcome-file-lists' tag. For some reason Eclipse adds this automatically but IntelliJ doesn't. If this isn't added, the App Engine deployment server points to the default index.jsp

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>my-entry-page.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```